# Using Liferay, SpringMVC and @RequestMapping, am I missing something?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, liferay

I'm trying to integrate SpringMVC with Liferay, up until now I have had mixed success, but this particular issue is driving me crazy. I have this very crude Controller

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
    public class AppointmentsController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView showAppointments(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) {
        return new ModelAndView("view");
    }

    @RequestMapping(params={"action=addAppointment"}) // render phase
    public String showAddAppointmentsForm(Model model) {
        //return new ModelAndView("add_appointment");
        System.out.println("TEST");
        return "add_appointment";
    }

}
```

The very first mapping, works fine, the portlet that this controller is responsible for renders flawlessly. In the jsp file that contains the view of the portlet, I have this

```
<aui:button-row>

    <portlet:actionURL var="addAppointmentURL">
        <portlet:param name="action" value="addAppointment" />
    </portlet:actionURL>

    <aui:button onClick="${addAppointmentURL}" value="Add New Appointment" />
    <aui:button type="button" value="Appointment History" />

</aui:button-row>
```

Now, the problem is that when I click on the "Add New Appointment" button, the action request doesn't get processed by showAddAppointmentsForm in the controller, instead I get

```
org.springframework.web.portlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No matching handler method found for portlet request: mode 'view', p hase 'ACTION_PHASE', parameters map['action' -> array<String>['addAppointment']]
```

I have tried lots of stuff, changed the portlet mode from VIEW to EDIT - didn't work, changed @RequestMapping of the showAddAppointmentsForm method to @ActionMapping - that work, but it insists that the decorated method should be void ergo I can't return the new jsp file that I want rendered.

I have referenced the documentation here -> http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html#portlet-ann-requestmapping-arguments but as far as I can see I'm doing the same things.

It's driving me crazy, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after the answer of @Danish, I kinda got on track what I did is:

```
@RenderMapping(params={"action=addAppointment"}) // render phase
public String showAddAppointmentsForm(Model model) {
    //return new ModelAndView("add_appointment");
    System.out.println("TEST");
    return "add_appointment";
}
```

Notice the @RenderMapping anotation, not @RequestMapping or @ActionMapping.

In the view:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="addAppointmentURL">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="addAppointment"></portlet:param>
</portlet:renderURL>

<aui:button onClick="${addAppointmentURL}" value="Add New Appointment" />
```

Answer (score 2):

try this `@ActionMapping(params = "action=addAppointment")`

More info here http://www.opensource-techblog.com/2012/09/render-and-action-methods-in-spring-mvc.html

Comment: Thanks, dude, your link pointed me in the right direction... actually I feel kinda stupid right now, I'm gonna post an answer saying what I did...